# C# DataTable Bind to GridView than export to Excel - Column with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, export-to-excel

I'm working on C# project (webform). 
I get data from the DB through a DataTable.

I initially bind my datas to the GridView to export it in a .xls file.
But I need to add columns which will have the same name.

```
¤-----------------------------------
| Global Information | Property |
¤----------------------------------- 
| Name |  NickName   |   Name   |
|
```

I though that the best way to reach this was to refer to the 2nd row because there is more details on this row. But I guess that the DataTable cannot have 2 column with the same name. So my question is : Is it possible to create 2 cells in the same column (on another row) like I show it on `Global Information` ? (Name and NickName refer to the same Column).

In case of it's not possible, Is there any other way to reach this aim please ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to marge two columns?

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you need to marge the first cell.
here is the syntax for merging cells while export

```
Sheet.Range[Sheet.Cells[1, 1], Sheet.Cells[2, 1]].Merge();
```

2)I have another option for you: create simple temple with whatever format you needed. and add your data in in

here is the example:

```
try
    {
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\ExcelFromTemplate.xlsx");
        FileInfo template = new FileInfo(@"C:\Example.xlsx");

        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile , template))
        {

           //Added This part
           foreach (ExcelWorksheet aworksheet in xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                aworksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = aworksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value;
            }

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["My Data"];

            ExcelCell cell = worksheet.Cell(5, 1);
            cell.Value = "15";

            //worksheet.Cell(5, 1).Value = "Soap";

            xlPackage.Save( );
            //Response.Write("Excel file created successfully");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.WriteFile(ex.InnerException.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I don't really know how does it work, could you give me a sample of this please ?

Comment: @wytes : i have updated my answer please check. I hop this work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a nomenclature, per example:

TypeOfObject,Owner,Child

So you get by names:

colGlobalName, colGlobalNickName, colPropertyName